# How can I change close tag of HTML using Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to change close tag of HTML using Intellij shortcut?

`<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records"></input>`

above code, I would like to change blow code using Intellij shortcut

`<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alt+Enter` on tag, **Collapse empty tag** will change

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works my IntelliJ IDEA, I have a question one more. Could I change tag in all document?

Comment: you can hit `Alt+Enter` on tag, then hit `Right` and choose 'Fix all "XML Tag empty body" problems in file'